# how to resume Mongodb M0 Cluster?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go, mongo-go-driver

MongoDB cluster(free) paused only after a couple hours of inactivity (as opposed to the stated 7 days for the free cluster).

I have tried to resume using `mongosh` and through my `Go` code but it still does not work. This is my second time encountering this issue, the first time I assumed it was a non-anachronistic error and terminated the cluster but now it does not look like it. i would love to find out a better way to handle this issue.

here are my error logs:

> from the Go driver

```
server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: cluster[].mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: connection(cluster0-shard-00-00.r3cqf.mongodb.net) socket was unexpectedly closed: EOF }
```

> from mongosh in terminal

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 32.65.3.208:27017 closed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple hours of combing through the error logs, I realized my issue was authorization related.

To fix this, navigate through the network/settings section of your `Mongodb cluster` and set the cluster to accept connection requests from your current IP -- mine had changed when I switched internet sources. You could also just set it to accept requests from all IP addresses by inputting `0.0.0.0` in the IP address field. Granted this is definitely not the best solution when working in prod but for now(on local machine), it'll do.

Comment: How long does it take for changing the accepted connection to take effect? Mine took more than half an hour.